# Asp MVC 3: Dynamically resolve relative resources in views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, relative-path

I have a **javascript application** that runs **in a view (index.cshtml)**.

**Problem:**
The problem is all **relative paths** are **relative to the current url**, which would be ok in a simple html webapp but not in asp mvc. The js-app shouldn't have to bother whether it's served in a normal html file or via a asp mvc page.

I.e. http://www.domain.com/<controller>/<action>/ contains a script **test.js**. This script loads an external xml file searching relative to it ie. "**data/data.xml**". The resulting url reads http://www.domain.com/<controller>/<action>/data/data.xml. This isn't found.

**Question:**
Is there a way to route static files (images,..., maybe even js files) to the content folder like "**~/Content/controller/action/<pathToFile>/**"?

Any help appreciated!

Lg
warappa

PS: I know about Url.Content() but that doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution doesn't require mapping - just a simple html tag in the header:

```
<base href="@(Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped) + 
    Url.Content("~/content/controller/action/"))" />
```

Lg
warappa

**EDIT**
Some browsers need an absolute url - sample updated.

Answer (score 1):

In you can use absolute URL addresses to access you static resources:

```
$('img').attr('src', '/Content/Pictures/picture1.png');
```

or

```
<script src="/Scripts/script.js"></script>
```

This way you will allways get the same resources relative to the page base address, no matter if you load the script in a `/{Controller}/{Action}/{View}`,  `{Area}/{Controller}/{Action}/{View}`, a custom route or even in a static script html page.

Or perhaps what you're looking for is the use of css files, since CSS's `url('<path>')` resolves the addresses relative to the CSS file's location. You would just need to import the one CSS file that had all the resource (image?) file paths. Then the scripts could reference the distinct class names, thus not being location aware at all. This is what libraries like jQuery UI do. But again this would require a fixed folder structure relative to the CSS document.

Comment: Sure, but than the application is aware of it's location ("So I'm in a Asp MVC webapp..."). I'm looking for a solution that reassembles a plain html behaviour.  Thanks anyway

Comment: No, its not aware that it's an Asp.net MVC app, its just has a required structure. You could use the same script in a php script if you wanted, but you would need to keep the static files directories.

Comment: OK, I was not precise enough. 
I would prefer a solution where a js-app just "sees" "css/style.css" or "images/background.jpg" - relative paths. 

Another problem with the starting slash is you expect it NOT to be in a virtual path - which is false in my special case.